# PHP, UTF-8, IIS and a Fileupload

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, utf-8

I'm using PHP 5.3 with MSSQL-Server 2005 and MSSQL-Server (PDO) driver from MS.

I recently struggled a litte bit with the new version of the driver and the charset it uses to pass data from the DB. So I decided to configure my whole application to UTF-8 to avaoid these kind of issues in the future.

So I changed the database to use unicode-datatypes, configured the HTML header and set up Eclipse to save the codefiles in UTF-8 format. Also I added the correspondig accept-charset tag to all my HTML forms. So far so good. Everything worked as expected but now I'm stuck with a new issue.

I wrote a simple script that can upload files using a HTML form and save them on my webserver (Windows Server 2003 with IIS6). This worked perfectly until I switched to UTF. When I upload a file with special chars in the filename, these are not saved correctly. Uplading a File named "ÄÖÜ.txt" ends up with a file named "Ã„Ã–Ãœ.txt" on my webserver. This can be a pain because all further processing of these files depends on hyperlinks which are not correct any more.

I tried to several possible solutions like this:

```
$isMoved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'],"myFolder". utf8_encode($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']));
```

But I'm always ending upth eiher having a correct file name on the server's filesystem or the other was around.

Anyone an idea? :D

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Comment: Do you've already changed the charset of the HTML and PHP file to UTF-8?

Comment: How are you looking at files on your filesystem? Are they UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am not completely wrong, the filename is encoded in UTF-8. Just decode it using mb_convert_encoding():

```
$filename = mb_convert_encoding($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'], 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
$isMoved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], "myFolder".$filename);
```

BurninLeo

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP 5.6 with IIS8 on Windows Sever 2012 I finally managed to get files with umlauts correctly uploaded, shown and downloaded by using

```
$filename = mb_convert_encoding(basename($_FILES['file']['name']),'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

in my upload script and

```
$filename = utf8_encode(basename($file));
```

in my display and download script.

When such an uploaded file is to be deleted, the filename passed to unlink may have to be converted to ISO-8859-1 again, using mb_convert_encoding.